# How to add 2 jScrollPane to my page and each one has different CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I have on my page 2 DIVs that uses jScrollPane and I want each one to have its own track bar, by default this property exist in CSS file and applied to the 2 DIVs.

I want to add a specific track bar to the second DIV without interacting withe first one.

How I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you given each a separate id? You should be able to target the css to each pane by its individual id

Comment: You can see a way to do this already even in the jScrollPane basic examples http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the second scroll pane in an element with a class or an id and then target your CSS rules to tracks nested inside that.

e.g. (assuming that you are using [jScrollPane 2](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="scroll-pane">
        [content]
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS:

```
#wrapper .jspTrack
{
    background: red;
}
```

This will only effect the track within the div with an id of "wrapper".

Hope it helps!